# generate pipe delimited file through codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, text-files

I am using the below for csv export but i want to export as a pipe delimeted output text file format.
My code generates a txt file using PHP's fputcsv function.
For the delimiter, I am trying to use '|'.

this mycode:

```
function to_CSV($table) {

    $file_csv = "file_csv.csv";
    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w'); 

    $query = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='htmltable' AND TABLE_NAME='$table'";
    $result = mysqli_query(db_connect(),$query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
            $header[] = $row[0];
    }

    header('Content-type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file_csv);
    fputcsv($fp, $header);

    $query  ="SELECT * from $table";
    $result = mysqli_query(db_connect(),$query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
            fputcsv($fp, $row);
    }
    exit;
}
fclose($fp);
$contents = file_get_contents($file_csv);
$contents = str_replace(",", "|", $contents);
file_put_contents($file_csv, $contents);
```

How to implementation in codeigniter. help me out please.
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> according to the docs `fputcsv` format line as CSV and write to file pointer, it has a third parameter which expects a delimiter - take a look at 
>   https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv

In your case it means

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    fputcsv($fp, $row, '|');
}
```

however the main question is - if you use Codeigniter as underlying Framework - why dont you use the model principle and aside of that the provided query builder? - it will make your life much easier.

> You can find more informations in their very well written documentation. Take a look at https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html?highlight=model